# Counting occurrences between pattern matches in data file and generating a report

Tags: awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have a file structured like this:

```
MATCH A and B
001
005
101

MATCH A and C
020
400

MATCH B and C
001
156
807
920
```

I want to generate a report that looks like:

```
A and B: 3
A and C: 2
B and C: 4
```

I imagine the tools to use are sed/awk. I know that sed can print lines between pattern matches, but the following ends up printing out the whole file.

```
sed -n '/^MATCH/,/^MATCH/p' file.txt | wc -l
```

This returns the number of lines in the whole file. Any tips on where to look at next? It seems that this isn't the most common task and I haven't been able to find many other suggestions.

Comment: to clear up any confusion: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines. period. full stop. for anything else you need awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk -v RS= '{print $2,$3,$4":",NF-4}' file
A and B: 3
A and C: 2
B and C: 4
```

Since record are separated by one blank line, and  `RS` is set to nothing,
we just have to count the fields `NF` minus first line.

---

This may be better:

```
awk -v RS= -F"\n" '{print $1":",NF-1}' file
MATCH A and B: 3
MATCH A and C: 2
MATCH B and C: 4
```

Or remove the  `MATCH` word:

```
awk -v RS= -F"\n" '{sub("MATCH ","",$1);print $1":",NF-1}' file
A and B: 3
A and C: 2
B and C: 4
```

Comment: You don't need GNU awk for any of that. wrt RS values, you only need GNU awk if you need an RS with more than 1 character. Setting `RS=` invokes paragraph mode which is POSIX and supported by all awks (probably except old, broken awk of course).

Comment: I was told by someone that setting RS to nothing was a `gnu awk` function.  Thanks for info.

Comment: No, it'll work in nawk, /usr/xpg4/bin/awk, etc., etc. too. It's just when you want to use a multi-char regexp as the RS like you can with FS that you need gawk. You're welcome.